# What Are the Top UX Enterprise-level Methology Considerations?

Tags: response-time, enterprise

I've read much about Enterprise Methodology considerations being required for user experience requirements,design, and implementation in relation to providing a great UX for today's enterprise workers (i.e., workers in business, corporate, etc). However, with increased consumerization, driving largely by mobile, and BYOD (Bring Your Own Device), what does this really mean today?

My question specifically is for enterprise methodologies and UX - so what are the top enterprise methodologies to *add* or *consider* when designing a great user experience? Are they things like performance, scalability, security, out of the box onboarding reducing cost of ownership, productivity, etc or something else? These need to be added top of end user efficiency, effectiveness, and satisfaction, but what are those top enterprise UX considerations?

Comment: Enterprise and UX seems to be contradictory in some ways, as the objectives of the business doesn't necessarily match with that of the users (e.g. pricing). Also, there are two different layers of users to consider in the enterprise application because these types of software require usage by system administrators to configure and manage the users, plus there are actual users that carry out tasks using the functions of the software.

Comment: @MichaelLai I disagree, in many cases the UX work being done in an enterprise is on programs designed to be used by the staff of that enterprise. In those cases the needs of the user and the needs of the enterprise are perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Enterprise does not really change the methodology. What it does do is that you as a designer have potentially an easier access some other tools - like training.

When designing, there are always trade-offs. For example, Efficiency v/s intutiveness is a common trade-off. If you are designing for completely unknown people, then you need to focus more on intutivness and might trade-off efficiency in the process. In case of enterprise, you can include a training component as a part of the solution and establish a process where users would be trained before using the product. This allows for improving efficiency as the intutivness is partly enhanced with training.